# ffmpeg - mapping multiple audios to one channel

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding

I want to output a video file with multiple sounds, but put them in one channel.
I've tried couple ways to do it, but I'm always given a video with multiple sound streams.
[Like this](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18738/ffmpeg-mapping-an-audio-file-with-2-channels-to-a-video-file)

My command is

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -i test_%03d.png 
-itsoffset 10 -ss 5 -t 20 -i s01.wav
-itsoffset 15 -ss 10 -t 30 -i s02.wav 
-map 0:v -map 1:a:0 -map 2:a:0 -c:v libopenh264 -c:a mp3 test.mp4
```

---

New command test

```
-framerate 30 -i test_%03d.png -ss 0.2 -t 1 -i sound01.wav -ss 1 -t 2 -i sound02.wav
-filter_complex
"[1] aformat=sample_fmts=s16p:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=mono [a1];
 [2] aformat=sample_fmts=s16p:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=mono [a2]; 
 [a1]adelay=400|400,apad[b1]; 
 [a2]adelay=900|900[b2]; 
 [b1][b2]amerge=2[a]" 
 -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v libopenh264 -c:a mp3 -ac 2 output.mp4
```

Because **filters could not choose their formats** error occurred, I added aformat to the command. 
But now another error is happening, **No channel layout for input 1** and output video lacks sound01, please help me out!

Comment: It works after changing channel_layouts=**mono** to **stereo**, but I'm still given **No channel layout for input 1** error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine multiple audio streams into one, you have to use filters to merge the streams:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i test_%03d.png -i s01.wav -i s02.wav \
       -filter_complex "[1][2]amerge=2[a]" \
       -map 0:v -map "[a]"   
       -c:v libopenh264 -c:a mp3 -ac 2 test.mp4
```

The `framerate` is the right option for image and raw streams.

The `-ac 2` downmixes the merged audio to 2 channels since that's the upper limit for the MP3 encoder.

---

For the updated command,

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i test_%03d.png 
       -ss 5 -t 20 -i s01.wav
       -ss 10 -t 30 -i s02.wav
       -filter_complex "[1]adelay=10000|10000,apad[a1];
                        [2]adelay=15000|15000[a2];
                        [a1][a2]amerge=2[a]" \
       -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v libopenh264 -c:a mp3 test.mp4
```

The `adelay` pads the audio in front, and takes value in milliseconds per channel. The `apad` pads audio at the end, and is needed because amerge ends with the shortest stream.

Comment: thanks, it does merge the streams, if I want to merge more audios can I just change **-filter_complex "[1][2][3][4]amerge=4[a]** ?

Comment: And I found that if I merge the streams the individual settings like **-itsoffset -ss -t** will be ignored.

Comment: *can I just change -filter_complex "[1][2][3][4]amerge=4[a] ?* --> yes.

Comment: Yes, those will be ignored and amerge will end with the shortest stream, so you should trim them beforehand.

Comment: so basically I can't do this in one line command, I need to trim them and make duration of sound files equal to the video duration, then merge them to the video?

Comment: You can but that's a longer filter_complex graph. I adapted your given command which doesn't do any trimming or offset.

Comment: I edited my command, please check it out!

Comment: thanks, I added adelay and apad to the command, and other error occurred, I added it to my post.

Comment: How to set **apad** parameter, when I have three or more sound streams?