# ffmpeg : how to set "apad" parameter

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, audio-streaming

My purpose is to map multiple audios to one channel and trim them.
There is my ffmpeg command.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i test_%03d.png 
       -ss 5 -t 20 -i s01.wav
       -ss 10 -t 30 -i s02.wav
       -filter_complex "[1]adelay=10000|10000,apad[a1];
                        [2]adelay=15000|15000[a2];
                        [a1][a2]amerge=2[a]" \
       -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v libopenh264 -c:a mp3 test.mp4
```

It works perfectly when there are only two sound streams, if I want to map three sound streams it didn't trim them properly.
I think the reason is I set **apad** incorrectly.
Please tell me how to map and trim multiple streams in the same time.

With more streams(adelay might not the actually number I used in the command):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i test_%03d.png 
       -i s01.wav
       -i s02.wav
       -i s03.wav
       -i s04.wav
       -filter_complex "[1]adelay=10000|10000,apad[a1];
                        [2]adelay=15000|15000,apad[a2];
                        [3]adelay=12000|15000,apad[a3];
                        [4]adelay=20000|10000[a4];
                        [a1][a2][a3][a4]amerge=4[a]" \
       -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v libopenh264 -c:a mp3 test.mp4
```

[Here is the original question](https://superuser.com/questions/1279735/ffmpeg-mapping-multiple-audios-to-one-channel)

Comment: Show the command you tried with three audio streams.

Comment: @Mulvya I added new command to my question.

Comment: Just to be sure, your command isn't trimming in advance any of the streams, only delaying and merging them. The merged stream should end when s04 does. What are you seeing?

Comment: I skipped the **-ss  -t** but I think it doesn't change the apad result, should I add **apad** parameter to each stream except last one?

Comment: Your command already does that, but yes. Add it all streams except one.

Comment: except last one? last one might be shortest is that ok?

Comment: Add to all streams except the one whose duration you want to preserve.

Comment: kinda confused, so it should be the longest one?

Comment: Decide which stream should be preserved in full. Add apads to all other streams.